# Laziness of (>>=) in folding

Tags: haskell, fold

Consider the following 2 expressions in Haskell:

```
foldl' (>>=) Nothing (repeat (\y -> Just (y+1)))
foldM (\x y -> if x==0 then Nothing else Just (x+y)) (-10) (repeat 1)
```

The first one takes forever, because it's trying to evaluate the infinite expression

```
...(((Nothing >>= f) >>= f) >>=f)...
```

and Haskell will just try to evaluate it inside out.

The second expression, however, gives Nothing right away. I've always thought foldM was just doing fold using (>>=), but then it would run into the same problem. So it's doing something more clever here - once it hits Nothing it knows to stop. How does foldM actually work?

Comment: in case you did not see it - there is a [nice article on the haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl') on those issues (not mentioning `foldM` but @dfeuer already helped out there)

Comment: Note that you can click on the "source" link from the documentation on Hackage to read the source yourself.

Answer (score 6):

`foldM` can't be implemented using `foldl`. It needs the power of `foldr` to be able to stop short. Before we get there, here's a version without anything fancy.

```
foldM f b [] = return b
foldM f b (x : xs) = f b x >>= \q -> foldM f q xs
```

We can transform this into a version that uses `foldr`. First we flip it around:

```
foldM f b0 xs = foldM' xs b0 where
  foldM' [] b = return b
  foldM' (x : xs) b = f b x >>= foldM' xs
```

Then move the last argument over:

```
  foldM' [] = return
  foldM' (x : xs) = \b -> f b x >>= foldM' xs
```

And then recognize the `foldr` pattern:

```
  foldM' = foldr go return where
    go x r = \b -> f b x >>= r
```

Finally, we can inline `foldM'` and move `b` back to the left:

```
foldM f b0 xs = foldr go return xs b0 where
  go x r b = f b x >>= r
```

This same general approach works for all sorts of situations where you want to pass an accumulator from left to right within a right fold. You first shift the accumulator all the way over to the right so you can use `foldr` to build a function that takes an accumulator, instead of trying to build the final result directly. Joachim Breitner did a lot of work to create the Call Arity compiler analysis for GHC 7.10 that helps GHC optimize functions written this way. The main reason to want to do so is that it allows them to participate in the GHC list libraries' fusion framework.

Answer (score 1):

One way to define `foldl` in terms of `foldr` is:

```
foldl f z xn = foldr (\ x g y -> g (f y x)) id xn z
```

It's probably worth working out why that is for yourself.  It can be re-written using `>>>` from `Control.Arrow` as

```
foldl f z xn = foldr (>>>) id (map (flip f) xn) z
```

The monadic equivalent of `>>>` is

```
f >=> g = \ x -> f x >>= \ y -> g y
```

which allows us to guess that `foldM` might be

```
foldM f z xn = foldr (>=>) return (map (flip f) xn) z
```

which turns out to be the correct definition.  It can be re-written using `foldr/map` as

```
foldM f z xn = foldr (\ x g y -> f y x >>= g) return xn z
```